# limit $x$ approach infinite problem of a $\ln$ function

Tags: calculus, limits

If $x$ approaches infinite, how do I end up with $0,5?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x-\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^{x^2}$$

Comment: Yes I am familiar with L'Hospital's rule. In fact, after a few times using this technique, I always come back with a 0/0 or infinite/infinite situation... I can't get out of a inderterminated formula.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange as:
$\\ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^2 \ln(\frac{1}{x}+1)$

Now define $ t = \frac{1}{x} $

The limit would be: $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(t+1)}{t^2}$

Now apply L'Hopital's rule to yield: $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{\frac{1}{t+1}}{2t} = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{2t^2 + 1} = \infty$

Comment: Thanks! The "t" trick is a great strategy !

Answer (score 0):

$$ \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^{x^2} = 
x^2 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right) = x^2\ln(1 + 1/x)
= x^2(1/x - 1/x^2 + \cdots)=x  \cdots$$

so it looks like the $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^{x^2} $$ does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by ``does not exist``? You mean it is not resolvable? I understand your explanation until you take out the ln from the equation...

Comment: @Cotopaxxi, i mean expression does not approach any number; instead it grows without bound as $x \to \infty.$

Comment: Oh! I see! Okay, I think I get it. Thank you @abel

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^{x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\ln{\left[\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^{x}\right]}^x = \lim_{x \to \infty}\ln e^x = \lim_{x \to \infty}x = \infty$$